# Access Ubuntu django server in VM from Windows

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, server

I have a Django server up and running in my Ubuntu VM using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I can access this in the VM browser. When I try to access using Windows browser the connection is never established. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Ubuntu VM settings go to Network -> Advanced Dropdown -> Port Forwarding button and there add
rule with Host Port 8000 and Guest Port 8000

**EDIT:**
[image]

[image]

When you set up this, then run server with this command

```py
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

Comment: Is this in ubuntu? I don't think I have the Advanced option in my network settings

Comment: @echinbic I should ask first. Is this Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox ?

Comment: @echinbic I added screenshot which shows where Advanced is.

Comment: I see it's not in the Ubunut Settings its the VM settings sorry misread your answer

Comment: After changing this setting do i need to restart vm?

Comment: After adding the port forwarding rule it still isn't connecting

Comment: Try to run server with this command `python manage.py runserver 0:8000`